# Uncountable and plural nouns: "space"

Tags: uncountable-nouns

Is this sentence true: *there isn't any more space* in my suitcase. In this case can we use *space* in plural or it remains as a singular form.

Comment: When you say "plural", what do you mean exactly? Could you add what you think the sentence would look like with the plural form?

Comment: Yes, so is "Space is infinite".

Comment: You could also say: **There are no more spaces in my suitcases (into which to pack small objects). Here you are referring to different gaps, all of which are now occupied.

Answer (score 1):

Countable *space* has boundaries.

> There aren't any more spaces in my suitcase.

This implies your suitcase has a number of separate compartments and you are out of them, like a bento box or tackle box.  Or it may be referring to things like interior pockets.

> There isn't any more space in my suitcase.

Either the space in your suitcase isn't compartmentalized or you don't know/care about the separate sections of space if they exist.

Comment: For your first example, I think you meant 'There **aren't** any more spaces in my suitcase'.

Comment: Although all the answers (so far at least) to this question are good, I like this one best because it clearly articulates that the choice between "space" and "spaces" depends on intended meaning.

Answer (score 0):

'Space' meaning 'empty area available for use' can be either countable or uncountable. In your example, it is uncountable, and we use the uncountable (singular) form:

There isn't **any more space** in my suitcase.

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/space):

> space
> noun UK
> [ C or U ]
> an empty area that is available to be used:
>
> Uncountable examples:
> Is there **any space** for my clothes in that cupboard?
> I need to make **(some) spac**e for Mark's things.
> When the roads are wet, you've got to leave **plenty of
> space** between you and the car in front.
>
> Countable examples:
> **The blank space** at the end of the form is for your name.
> We found **a parking space** close to the
> museum.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence:

> There isn't any more space in my suitcase.

is correct. *space* here means "an empty area", and is an uncountable noun. Using *spaces* with this meaning is incorrect.

Note that there are other meanings of "space", which are countable nouns. In those cases, you can use either the plural, or the singular form depending on the context.

- space: An area where an activity may take place

> I like this *space*. I'm going to work here.
>
> There are many *spaces* where I feel comfortable being myself.

- space: An empty position in text.

> There is usually a *space* after a period at the end of a sentence.
>
> You can press the spacebar multiple times to insert multiple *spaces*.